# Eclipse not recognizing .xml files

Tags: xml, eclipse

I have created a new JavaProject on Eclipse. When I try to create .xml file, Eclipse is not able to recognize it. It says "the word xml is not correctly spelled".

Can some one help me in resolving the issue. Thanks.

Comment: How do you create the file? Do you use right click > New > Other... > XML? What is your Eclipse version? Are you sure that the file is not recognized and not the string `xml` from a file? You could add it to the dictionary ...

Comment: @engineer When I click on File>new>Other I don't see any XML option in the list there. I created the file using File>New>File and saved it as Build.xml. My Eclipse version is 
Version: 3.8.1 Build id: debbuild. I am sure the file is not recognized as whole text is in black colour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which flavour of Eclipse have you installed ?
I guess the xml tooling provided by web tools platform is missing in your installation.

You can verify that be going to Help->Install Software-> What is installed-> Plugins-> Type xml . It must list down xml editor by WTP.
If this is the case then you need to install WTP over your current version.

You can also choose the first option of Eclipse for Java or Java EE developers https://eclipse.org/downloads/ depending upon your requirements.